# Missed Friday Prayers

Tags: practical-islam, punishment, forgiveness, jumuah

I normally leave for prayers at 12pm. But on a particular Friday, I was informed at 12:10pm as I was leaving that I have to be on standby due to vendor visiting my workplace and I have to provide support which will take 2 hours.

I feel bad and upset that i'm unable to attend prayers. Will I be punished for this?

> > Narated By Al-Ja'd ad-Damri : The Prophet (pbuh) said: He who leaves the Friday prayer (continuously) for three Friday on account of slackness, Allah will print a stamp on his heart. - Abu Dawud (Book 2, Hadith 1047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

> O you who believe (Muslims)! When the call is proclaimed for the
>   Salât (prayer) on the day of Friday (Jumu'ah prayer), come to the
>   remembrance of Allâh [Jumu'ah religious talk (Khutbah) and Salât
>   (prayer)] and leave off business (and every other thing), that is
>   better for you if you did but know![62:9]

As you already know this hadees, there are many other ahadees too. **You must repent to Allah and ask for forgiveness and make promise to of trying your best in future.** It is a sin and every sin has punishment, until or unless you have been forgiven by Allah for that sin. So repent and ask for forgiveness.
Besides it is a good sign you feel bad on sin and it is what is eman, when a momin do some sin, he feels like he is standing under a mountain and this mountain is going to be dropped on him any time. This is in a hadees but i don't remember complete reference. Just repent and do your best in future. Inshallah things will be fine.

For proper rulings, read [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83127) and [here](https://islamqa.info/en/36530)

### Allah knows best